# MissingManifestResourceException for FSharp.Core assembly

Tags: f#, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library

I use a F# PCL library in my Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal) project.

I have referenced the F# PCL library as a project. I've also referenced the FSharp.Core assembly since I need to use some of its types (in order to communicate with my F# PCL). I use a reference to the same physical assembly (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETCore\3.259.3.1\FSharp.Core.dll) that is used by default when creating a new F# PCL project.

As long as I build in any other configuration than Release - ARM, everything works. But when I switch to Release - ARM configuration (which I believe is the one provided by the Store to the users, based on the behavior of the app when downloaded directly from the Store), all hell breaks loose.

When I try to access the List.sortBy function, I get the following error:

> Error Code:
>
> -2146233036
>
> Error Message:
>
> The type initializer for 'FastGenericComparerTable`1' threw an
>   exception.
>
> Line Number:
>
> FSharp.Core
>
> Stack Trace:    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.FastGenericComparerCanBeNullT
>   at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array.stableSortWithKeys[T,TKey](T[]
>   array, TKey[] keys)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array.stableSortInPlaceBy[T,TKey](FSharpFunc`2
>   projection, T[] array)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule.SortBy[T,TKey](FSharpFunc`2
>   projection, FSharpList`1 list)    at
>   TaskCrunch.Data.ChildEntityTransforms.reorderTree[a](FSharpFunc`2
>   sortFunc, FSharpList`1 xs)    at
>   TaskCrunch.Data.ChildEntityTransforms.children(toDo x, FSharpList`1
>   ys, FSharpList`1 accumulated)    at
>   TaskCrunch.Data.ChildEntityTransforms.createTreeInternal@82(FSharpList`1
>   ys, FSharpList`1 resultSoFar)    at
>   TaskCrunch.Universal.ViewModel.ProjectDetailViewModel.<SortTasks>d__5c.MoveNext()
>   ----- INNER EXCEPTION ------ Message: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Prim-types' threw an exception.  Source:
>   FSharp.Core  StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives..cctor$cont@2181-2[T](Type
>   matchValue, Unit unitVar)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.FastGenericComparerTable`1..cctor()
>   HResult: -2146233036  HelpLink: Unknown
>
> ----- INNER EXCEPTION ------ Message: Exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' was thrown. 
>   Source: mscorlib  StackTrace:    at
>   System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at .$Prim-types..cctor() 
>   HResult: -2146233038  HelpLink: Unknown

Strangely, this does not appear to be my first call to FSharp.Core, since I call a List.map function before it, which seems to execute.

I suspect that something goes wrong in the build process, but I'm not sure where to look. I've tried recreating the F# PCL library from scratch to no avail.

Comment: Well, looks pretty sad.  It bombed twice, the second failure occurred when it tried to tell you why the first exception happened.  Pioneers have arrows in their back.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in the VS F# portable profile support.  Possibly a compiler bug (somehow this version of FSharp.Core is not properly fitted onto the portable profile), or possibly a project system bug (some kind of required build output is not getting created properly for ARM).

I would recommend opening this as a bug at https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/